# How to remove a series of individual letters from a string?

Tags: c#

Messing around with C# logic, trying to build a program where the user inputs a string, and then has the option to decide which letter is removed from said string.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a string of letters");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("please enter letters you would like removed");

char removedLetters = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

foreach (char letter in input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input.Replace(removedLetters,' ').ToLower());
}
```

This works, but not entirely. I will get rid of characters, but only when written in a specific way that corresponds with the original input.

e.g helloworld -> remove l = he  owor d

but helloworld -> remove elo = failure.

Can someone share some knowledge? Really trying to get better at logic, happy i got this far just need bit of guidance.

Cheers,

Andy

Comment: What does *failure* mean?

Comment: when someone types ELO you want to remove each of those letters or only that exact instance of that *string*?

Comment: Use the `.Replace(string , string)` overload rather than the char version. `input.Replace("l", String.Empty)`

Comment: failure as in an error message.

Comment: and yes i want to be able to remove those specific letters, not only in that exact instance, but in any i.e elo, ole, oel etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Jasen's comment from earlier something like this ...

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a string of letters");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        List<char> input_array = input.ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("please enter letters you would like removed");
        string removedLetters = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] remove_array = removedLetters.ToArray();

        for (int k = 0; k < remove_array.Count(); k++)
        { input_array.RemoveAll(r=>r== remove_array[k]);  }

        Console.WriteLine(new string(input_array.ToArray()));
```

Again, using Linq, in this case RemoveAll, to automate the heavy lifting. I have not tested how efficient these are, they are quick and simple solutions not necessarily the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to handle duplicates but C# has an Except operator that works on Arrays. So convert both strings to an array and something like this should work...

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a string of letters");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] input_array = input.ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("please enter letters you would like removed");
        string removedLetters =Console.ReadLine();
        char[] remove_array = removedLetters.ToArray();

        char[] leftover_array = input_array.Except(remove_array).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(new string(leftover_array));
```

Comment: ahh yes this works perfectly. Thank you! Is there a way i could have done this with my foreach loop? was also toying with possibly running 2 for loops on input and removedLetters and if they matched then remove duplicates? couldnt getr that one to work either.